# Why is this :after element being affected by line breaks?

Tags: css, webkit, pseudo-element

I have a simple menu coded up like this

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="container">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Villas & Yachts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Islands</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get In Touch</a></li>       
 </ul>
```

which looks like this
[image]

The little dots in-between each menu item are created using the :after pseudo element. Eveything is working fine, but I also need sub menus, which will be nested lists.

The problem is, when i add a line break to the menu like this

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="container">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Villas & Yachts</a>
    <!-- LINE BREAK -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Islands</a>
    <!-- LINE BREAK -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get In Touch</a></li>       
 </ul>
```

I get this result in Safari & Chrome (But not Firefox)...
[image]

It seems to me as though webkit is treating the whitespace as 'pre'. The CSS for the :after element looks like this

```
ul#main-menu li:after
{
    content: "\00b7";
    width: 61px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    border: rgba(225,225,225,0.25) 1px solid;
}
```

I've also tried setting `white-space: normal/nowrap` on the ul, li and :after elements which doesn't affect anything.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong, or is this a problem with Webkit/Firefox?

### UPDATE

I've created a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/zmVbH/

Comment: create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ with all required css

Comment: Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/zmVbH/

Comment: @Jason, It seems to affect webkit (so Safari & Chrome). Not been able to test in IE yet though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the line break is white space which makes the floated content drop a line. The issue can be reproduced by adding a single space between the `</a>` and `</li>`. Try making the inserted content `display:inline-block` instead of floated.

```
ul#main-menu li:after
{
    content: "\00b7";
    width: 61px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border: rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 1px solid;
    white-space: normal;        
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmVbH/1/).

### UPDATE BY OP

Yup, inline-block fixes this, but it's not quite that simple since inline-block has some patchy browser support.

```
ul#main-menu li:after
{
    content: "\00b7";
    width: 61px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    border: rgba(225,225,225,0.25) 1px solid;

    /* FIX */
    display:-moz-inline-stack; /* For older versions of Firefox */ 
    display:inline-block; /* Anything that supports inline-block */

    /* IE FIX */
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline; 
}
```